# Passing template vector literal as a parameter

Tags: c++, vector

So, lets say I have some function `print`:

```
template<typename T>
void print(std::vector<T> V)
```

To pass a vector to print, I have to do

```
std::vector<int> v {1,2,3,4,5};
print(v);
```

And that works fine. What I want to know is, is there any way to pass a vector literal to a function as a parameter?

So our function call becomes

```
print({1,2,3,4,5})
```

and no longer requires the initialization of another temporary variable?

I know I am able to use `std::initializer_list` but I would like to have the features of vector, `push_back`, `size`, etc.

So, is there any way to either call the function by passing a vector literal, or is there any way in the function declaration (or call) to cast an `initializer_list` as a vector of type T?

If it's not possible, is there a specific reason such as security?

I know I can do it if I specify the type, such as

```
void print(std::vector<int> V);
print({1,2,3,4});
```

But why not for templates as well? Seems like it'd be pretty much the same process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can very easily create a vector from the initialiser list:

```
template <class T>
void print(std::initializer_list<T> L)
{
  std::vector<T> V(L);
  // ...
}
```

[[Live example]](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/806d87b8a9a7ba30)

Naturally, you can also overload for the cases where you actually have a `std::vector` on hand:

```
template <class T>
void print(std::initializer_list<T> L)
{
  print(std::vector<T>(L));
}

template <class T>
void print(const std::vector<T> &V)
{
  // Print as required
}
```

---

To answer your question why you cannot use your original `print` template with an initialiser list directly: there is no way the compiler can deduce the `T`. Remember that templates can be specialised—there's no way to know that only a `std::vector<int>` can be initialised from a `std::initializer_list<int>`, for example. A specialisation of `std::vector<MyCustomType>` could perfectly legally provide such a constructor too.

---

And to react to comments: of course, if that is preferable for you, you can just construct the vector directly at call site:

```
template <class T>
void print(std::vector<T> V)
{
  // ...
}

print(std::vector<int>{1, 2, 3, 4, 5});
```

However, I consider adding an overload of `print` taking `std::initializer_list` superior to this solution.

Comment: Any way to do this inside the call to print itself instead of inside the function? So like a print((vector<T>){1,2,3,4,5}) or something like that? 

Upvoted answer because that works, just was hoping to do it inline instead of having to modify the function because of the system I'm working with.

Comment: @Kilenaitor Edited, but I consider adding an overload superior.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! And I will take a second look, but this works great for now. Thank you! :D

Answer (score 2):

`{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}` has no type.

It can be deduced as `std::initilizer_list<T>` though.

it cannot be deduce for `std::vector<T>`.

To solve your issue, you may add overload for `initializer_list`

```
template <typename T>
void print(std::initializer_list<T> ini)
{
    print(std::vector<T>(ini));
}
```

or transform the initializer_list explicitly to `vector`

```
template <typename T>
std::vector<T> as_vector(std::initializer_list<T> ini)
{
    return ini;
}
```

and then (with above method, you avoid to repeat type `T`, but `std::vector<int>{1, 2, 3, 4}` is an alternative)

```
print(as_vector({1,2,3,4}));
```